# What do I need to do to get mathjax to render? It works locally but not live

Tags: wordpress, mathjax

On my [wordpress webpage](https://www.kelliesmith.info/wordpress/?request=get_interest&page_id=2&m=1&i_effective=0) mathjax doesn't render - it shows
[image]

But if I take a copy of the page's code and load the html locally it renders OK:
[image]

What do I need to do to get the live web page to render?

The mathjax script included in the page is

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MathJax fails to load if the site is being viewed through HTTPS, which it is if HTTPS Everywhere. Disable HTTPS Everywhere for just this site, and then reload the page without HTTPS.

[Source](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10776/mathjax-not-working)

Comment: Or make the link to `cdn.mathjax.org` into an `https` link, or just use `//cdn.mathjax.org...` to let it use whatever was used to access the page initially.